# JS conditional clear value onClick of submit button

Tags: javascript, onclick, submit

I have a textbox with default value "Keywords". Note that this field is not required.

```
<input
       type="text"
       maxlength="255"
       class="cat_textbox"
       id="keyword_box"
       name="keyword_box"
       value="Keywords"
       onblur="if (this.value == 'Keywords') {this.value = '';}"
       onfocus="if (this.value == 'Keywords') {this.value = '';}"  />
```

What I would like to happen is that when I click on the submit button, before data gets submitted, some JS would check if value of "keyword_box"="Keywords". If yes, then clear out that value and then submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your submit button text input.. `onsubmit=clearDefaults()`

in your js --

```
function clearDefaults(){
var key = document.getElementById("keyword_box");
if(key.value == "Keywords")
key.value="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `submit` event handler of your form.

```
document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function () {
    var keywords = document.getElementById("keyword_box");
    if (keywords.value == "Keywords") {
        keywords.value = "";
    }
};
```

But from the looks of it, you seem to be trying to implement a "placeholder". In modern browsers, you can get this for free by using the `placeholder` attribute on the input element:

```
<input
       type="text"
       maxlength="255"
       class="cat_textbox"
       id="keyword_box"
       name="keyword_box"
       placeholder="Keywords" />
```